# How to type gmail body text in selenium webdriver

Tags: email, selenium, xpath

I am able to successfully compose the email but after adding subject of the mail..I am not able to find any element `Xpath` or `id` or `className` to type the body of the mail..

I used:- **Type (send keys) the email content to the editable div: "//div[@class='gmail_default']" (or "//div[@aria-label='Message Body']")** for the Gmail body text..

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Message Body']")).sendKeys("This is the test email send to test the selenium script.");
```

it worked once..after that it stopped working.

Please can anyone help...
******************Code**********************

```
public class TestSelenium {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

   System.setProperty("WebDriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement id =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']"));
    id.click();
    id.sendKeys("Email");
    WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']"));
    next.click();
    WebElement psw = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
    psw.clear();
    psw.sendKeys("Password");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signIn']"));
    login.click();
    WebElement compose = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':44']/div/div"));
    compose.click();
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.className("vO"));
    to.sendKeys("Email_id of Receiver");
    WebElement sub = driver.findElement(By.className("aoT"));
    sub.sendKeys("Login Successful");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Message Body']")).sendKeys("This is the test email send to test the selenium script.");

    WebElement send = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':8m']"));
    send.click();
```

}
}

Comment: why don't you use Tab to move control to Message Body from Subject.

Comment: I tried with TAB also but Tab gives control to send button..

Comment: can you provide step by step code.

Comment: I have added step by step code above

Answer (score 0):

Try using : `sub.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);`

Answer (score 0):

I use a Firefox extension to give me a list of locators which are clickable. Install this,

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/?src=api

then right click on the body of the email in the firefox window and you'll see the C#/Java etc options. Select one a then use that as your webElement

Comment: I tried with this and able to write the body of mail once but when i tried second time it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried below code to find element and it worked, I've tested 4 times and it worked all times.

But before that, make sure you have put enough wait to open Compose section.

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':n6']")).sendKeys("Balle Balle");

Hope this will help you. If this does not solve your issue then let me know what error you are facing.
Thank You,
Ed D, India.